# Large matrix: solve(crossprod(X)) when dim(X) = 100,000:5000

Tags: r

I need to do run a simple two-stage least squares regression on large data matrices. This just requires some `crossprod()` and `solve()` commands, but the matrices have dimensions 100,000 by 5000 matrix. My understanding is that holding a matrix like this in memory would take up a bit less than 4GB of memory. Unfortunately, my 64-bit Win7 machine only has 8GB of RAM. When I try to manipulate the matrices in question, I get the usual 'can't allocate vector of size' message.

I have considered a number of options such as the `ff` and `bigmemory` packages. However, the base R functions for the matrix operations I need only support the usual matrix object type, not the `bigmatrix` type.

It seems like it may be possible to extend the code from `biglm()`, but I'm on a tight schedule for this project, so I wanted to check-in with you all to see if there existed a ready-made solution for problems like this. Apologies if this was addressed before (I couldn't find it) or if the question is too generic.

Comment: Have you tried removing unneeded programs/services from memory? Using a basic theme rather than an Aero one might help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a ready-made solution exist in [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=biglm), the package you already identified.  Linear regression can work with an updating scheme; that basic property is implemented in the package.

Dump your data to disk, say to SQLite and study the package documentation and proceed in, say, 10 chunks on 10,000 each.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dirk (big fan of your work on Rcpp BTW). But I'm confused. 2SLS requires that I regress my matrix X on the matrix of instruments Z, and that I use the predictions from this model to estimate the coefficients b from the "second stage": P=(Z'Z)^{-1} Z'X,  b=(X'PX)^{-1} X'Py, X-hat=PX.  No matter what formula I use, biglm() will only give me predictions as a vector of values for a unique left-hand side variables, so I can't manually do the two stages by first generating a matrix of X-hat=PX.

Comment: It's been a few years, but can't you run 2SLS as two distinct regressions?  Each of those can then use biglm to overcome memory constraints.  Or just rent an Amazon EC2 instance with more ram...

Comment: Yeah. It would still have been nice to get a more generic solution so I could also apply it to different problems. Still, the code for biglm seems pretty straightforward, so I'll probably end up playing around with it a bit if/when I find some time. Thanks!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That is my understanding as well. It's pretty much the reason it's called "two-stage".