# R function to solve large dense linear systems of equations?

Tags: r, matrix, large-data

Sorry, maybe I am blind, but I couldn't find anything specific for a rather common problem:

I want to implement

```
solve(A,b)
```

with 
    A 
being a large square matrix in the sense that command above uses all my memory and issues an error (b is a vector with corresponding length). The matrix I have is not sparse in the sense that there would be large blocks of zero etc.
There must be some function out there which implements a stepwise iterative scheme such that a solution can be found even with limited memory available.

I found several posts on sparse matrix and, of course, the Matrix package, but could not identify a function which does what I need. I have also seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724515/large-matrix-solvecrossprodx-when-dimx-100-0005000) but
    biglm
produces a complete linear model fit. All I need is a simple solve. I will have to repeat that step several times, so it would be great to keep it as slim as possible.

I already worry about the "duplication of an old issue" and "look here" comments, but I would be really grateful for some help.

Comment: if you could figure out the name of the *algorithm* you wanted it would be easier to see if it was implemented somewhere in a lower-level library like LAPACK, LINPACK, Armadillo ... and then look for R wrappers (e.g. in the `Matrix` or `RCppArmadillo` packages).

Comment: e.g. "out-of-core" seems useful: https://www.google.ca/search?q=solve+out-of-core+linear

Comment: @flodel:       Assume that it is sufficiently large and sufficiently dense as I described it above: it uses all of the memory and the sparse matrix methods don't help. 
More precisely: take a 10k x 10k matrix with virtually no zero element. Applying `solve()` uses up >3.6 GB RAM which is feasible on a 64bit system but not on my 32bit system.

Comment: @BenBolker :     Thanks for the link! I had a look on it, but couldn't find an implementation in R yet. The documentation of the Matrix package apparently doesn't even mention the word 'memory' and RccpArmadillo require C++ programming which I am not yet capable of. Did I oversee anything which directly implements such a method in plain R?

Comment: looking at the High Performance Task View http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html leads to the `pbdDMAT` package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbdDMAT/index.html , which might do what you want. Haven't dug into it.

Comment: Would conjugate gradient or a relative iterative method not work for you? That workers for very large systems and has a low memory footprint, see e.g. https://github.com/styvon/cPCG or https://github.com/kisungyou/Rlinsolve ...